# Get the last in and out time for ticket mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a ticketing system, and I want to generate a report for some set of data as following:

- First time ticket has assigned to IU pool.
- Last time ticket has assigned to IU pool.
- Last time ticket has assigned from IU pool to any other pool.
- Time to repair (Shows how long the ticket stayed for last time in that pool)
- Ticket number.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aims_item_group_transfare` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `fromGroupId` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `toGroupId` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `transfareDate` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fromGroupId` (`fromGroupId`),
  KEY `toGroupId` (`toGroupId`),
  KEY `transfareDate` (`transfareDate`),
  KEY `item_id_ix` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The above table stores the transfer time, between the different pools.

Here is what I wrote

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(TMIN.transfareDate)) AS 'First Time TO IU'
,FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)) AS 'Last Time TO IU', FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAXOut.transfareDate))'Last time from IU'
, A.item_id AS 'Ticket Number' 
,
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)),FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAXOut.transfareDate))) , ' Days ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)),FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAXOut.transfareDate))), 24), ' Hours ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)),FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAXOut.transfareDate))), 60), ' Minutes ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)),FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TMAXOut.transfareDate))), 60), ' Seconds'
) AS 'Time to repair'

FROM  aims_item_group_transfare T
LEFT JOIN  aims_items A ON T.item_id = A.item_id
LEFT JOIN  aims_item_group_transfare TMIN ON T.item_id = TMIN.item_id AND TMIN.toGroupId=20
LEFT JOIN  aims_item_group_transfare TMAX ON T.item_id = TMAX.item_id AND TMAX.toGroupId=20
LEFT JOIN  aims_item_group_transfare TMAXOut ON T.item_id = TMAXOut.item_id AND TMAXOut.fromGroupId=20
WHERE T.fromGroupId=20
AND T.transfareDate>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-05 00:00:00') AND T.transfareDate<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-12 23:59:59')
GROUP BY T.item_id
```

My query does not work probably. It returns some null dates which is not correct. I hope that any body would help.

Comment: I tried to figure out the query but the huge `CONCAT` was too much for me - I'll need at least one more coffee :) It's probably not doing you any good either. Try selecting the values singly, without concatenating, and work out the query basics like that. Note that if any of the values selected in `CONCAT` are null, the result of the entire `CONCAT` will be null.

Comment: I hope you will enjoy your coffee :)
Anyway, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Using joins against subselects, with each one getting the relevant min or max:-

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TMIN.MinTransfareDate) AS 'First Time TO IU',
FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAX.MaxTransfareDate) AS 'Last Time TO IU', 
FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAXOut.MaxFromTransfareDate)'Last time from IU',
A.item_id AS 'Ticket Number' ,
CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAX.MaxTransfareDate),FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAXOut.MaxFromTransfareDate)) , ' Days ',
    MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAX.MaxTransfareDate),FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAXOut.MaxFromTransfareDate)), 24), ' Hours ',
    MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAX.MaxTransfareDate),FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAXOut.MaxFromTransfareDate)), 60), ' Minutes ',
    MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAX.MaxTransfareDate),FROM_UNIXTIME(TMAXOut.MaxFromTransfareDate)), 60), ' Seconds'
) AS 'Time to repair'
FROM  aims_item_group_transfare T
LEFT JOIN  aims_items A ON T.item_id = A.item_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, toGroupId, MIN(transfareDate) AS MinTransfareDate FROM aims_item_group_transfare GROUP BY item_id, toGroupId) TMIN ON T.item_id = TMIN.item_id AND TMIN.toGroupId = T.fromGroupId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, toGroupId, MAX(transfareDate) AS MaxTransfareDate FROM aims_item_group_transfare GROUP BY item_id, toGroupId) TMAX ON T.item_id = TMAX.item_id AND TMAX.toGroupId = T.fromGroupId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, fromGroupId, MAX(transfareDate) AS MaxFromTransfareDate FROM aims_item_group_transfare GROUP BY item_id, fromGroupId) TMAXOut ON T.item_id = TMAXOut.item_id AND TMAXOut.fromGroupId = T.fromGroupId
WHERE T.fromGroupId = 20
AND T.transfareDate>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-05 00:00:00') AND T.transfareDate<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-12 23:59:59')
```